# Вопросительный знак в теле тэга XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Следующий код на python:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
dom = ET.parse(u'C:\\bla.xml')
```

Вылетает с `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: switching encoding: encoder error, line 1, column 42`

Если тело xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<АНКЕТА_ЗЛ>
  <АнкетныеДанные>
    <МестоРождения>
      <ГородРождения>?</ГородРождения>
    </МестоРождения>
  </АнкетныеДанные>
</АНКЕТА_ЗЛ>
```

И при этом корректно обрабатывается, если тело:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<АНКЕТА_ЗЛ>
  <АнкетныеДанные>
    <МестоРождения>
      <ГородРождения>,</ГородРождения>
    </МестоРождения>
  </АнкетныеДанные>
</АНКЕТА_ЗЛ>
```

Вопросительные знаки запрещены в теле XML документов? Или это баг ElementTree? Как правильно работать с содержимым XML документов, если написать там могут все, что угодно (но не знаки <>), в том числе и знак вопроса?

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть знак вопроса в `<![CDATA[...]]>`

Comment: Все равно имеет место эта ошибка. Кодировка файла cp1251.

Comment: Наверное, ошибка.

Насколько помню, в "парсируемой" части xml запрещены только 3 символа -- `<, & и >`.

Однако обратите внимание на:

    switching encoding: encoder error

Видимо, проблема не столько в xml-парсере, сколько в перекодировщике из cp-1251 в unicode.

Comment: Я подсунул xml в `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse`. Он проглотил его вместе с `?`, правда с русскими заголовками тегов работать отказался.

Comment: @Donil, вот-вот, если имена тэгов английские - работает без проблем. Если имена русские, но знак не ? - работает без проблем. А вот русские символы в именах + ? в теле дает сбой.
____
@avp в Notepad++ я устанавливаю кодировку в cp1251, и с клавиатуры печатаю "?". И получаю эту ошибку. Возможно, где-то есть какая-то автоматическая конвертация, например, при наличии русских символов в unicode, не знаю, но разве отказываться от знака ? из-за русских названий тэгов?

Comment: А в utf-8 работает?

Comment: Да, дело, похоже, было в кодировке и гибкости виндовых технологий по отношению к кодировке (корректное отображение символов разных кодировок в одном файле, соответственно, проблемы с декодированием и кривые руки авторов тестов, которые понатворили эту муть), удалось колдовством добиться работы.